# Не приравниваются одинаковые объекты

Tags: javascript, typescript

У меня есть сайт с карточками, данные об каждой карточке я храню в localstorage под ключом "movie", для отображение данных я перебираю через *ngFor массив в котором хранятся все объекты карточек. Этот массив я получаю с помощью метода (ниже в скринах все будет). Получается я хочу при удаление что бы передавался объект на кнопку которого я нажимаю. И после удалялся из массива, но суть в том что почему мне выдает что ошибку что такого объекта нет в этом массиве. Я ниже приложил скриншот в котором я пытаюсь сравнить абсолютно два одинаковых объекта и мне выдается false
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Объекты считаются равными, если они ссылаются на один и тот же объект... Вероятно у тебя не так, значит и такое сравнение тебе не подойдет.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я разобрался, когда я использую получение movies (массива с объектами) через метод, а надо было напрямую использовать, крч я разобрался в чем дело, спасибо)